# How do I remove <p> tag and its content from HTML using php

Tags: php, html

Below is the text I need to remove `<p>` tags from

```
<p> Addiction, stress and subjective wellbeing</p> 
<p> The need and significance of traditional shop lot pavements in the context of town conservation in Malaysia</p> 
<p> The role of wage and benefit in engaging employee commitment</p>
```

I tried this

```
$title= preg_replace('#<p>(.*?)</p>#', '', $title['result']);**
```

But still am Getting `<p>` tags, any ideas?

Comment: In case you're looking to remove specific tags without removing content, you might find this `strip_tags_only` function helpful: https://gist.github.com/aalaap/0176bc6b2df799038f711cb6718dcddc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just to remove p tags you can do this

```
$text=str_ireplace('<p>','',$text);
$text=str_ireplace('</p>','',$text);
```

Comment: If you do just that then 1. It will only be able catch empty p tag such as `<p>` and; 2. Content of this tag will stay.

Comment: then use regular expression

Comment: -1 because it is not a definitive solution. You have to use regular expressions as in the answer below.

Comment: @MarcoPanichi If answer given by me solved the problem of questioner then how does that cause problem to you. If your problem cant be solve using the above solution then raise your question in stackoverflow instead of down vote my answer.

Answer (score 22):

You should use this regular expression to catch `<p>` tag and all of its content:

```
'/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i'
```

Working example to catch and remove `<p>` tag and all of its content:

```
$title = "<div>Text to keep<p class='classExample'>Text to remove</p></div>";
$result = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '', $title);
echo $result;
```

**[Please see live demo on Codepad](http://codepad.org/dEpWYXcX)**

If you want to use regular expressions to parse HTML - then you will not be able to do this.

Read more about your matter here: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577662#3577662)

Comment: $title = preg_replace('%<p[^>]*>\s*(\[([^\[\]]+)\].*?\[/\2\])\s*</p>%s', '', $result['title']); Is is Correct

Comment: Use this in your case: `$title = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '', $result['title']);`

Comment: If you want to strip the tags, in myu opinion, it means that you want to keep the content of the tag, but not the tag itself. To do so, you need to add \1 in the second parameter of the preg_replace function : $result = preg_replace('/<p\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/p>/i', '\1', $title);

Answer (score 7):

Try:

If you want to remove `<p>` tag only

```
$html = "
<p> Addiction, stress and subjective wellbeing</p> 
<p> The need and significance of traditional shop lot pavements town</p> 
<p> The role of wage and benefit in engaging employee commitment</p>
";

echo strip_tags($html);
```

If you want to remove `<p>` tags and its `content`

```
$html = preg_replace('#\<p>[{\w},\s\d"]+\</p>#', "", $html);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<div id=\"main_content\">" . strip_tags($row[main_content]) . "</div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to strip *all* the markup, go with [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).

Comment: No I need To Save This Data To Database After Remove the p tags am using ckeditor

Answer (score 2):

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow p and a tag
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This code removes one p-tag:

```
function parse($html) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $ps = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
    //die('<pre>'.print_r($ps,1).'</pre>');
    if ($ps->length === 1){
        $p = $ps->item(0);
        return $p->nodeValue;
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example to strip all `<p>` tags with or without the closing / after the first `<`

```php
$content = '<p> Addiction, stress and subjective wellbeing</p>
<p> The need and significance of traditional shop lot pavements in the context of town conservation in Malaysia</p>
<p> The role of wage and benefit in engaging employee commitment</p>';
    $new_content = preg_replace('/<(|\/)p>/', '', $content);
    dump($new_content);
    die('HERE');
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1=html_entity_decode("<p>your text with p tag</p>");
$data2=str_ireplace('<p>',' ',$data1);
$data3=str_ireplace('</p>',' ',$data2); 
echo $data3;
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit what this code block does?